# 2D Slider does not move in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

Consider the following simple code:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Point[{pt[[2]], -pt[[1]]}]], {pt, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

The purpose of this code is to show (y,-x) if the slider is in (x,y). However, it turns out that the 2D slider does not move. Why does this happen?

Comment: Need to specify {xmin,ymin},{xmax,ymax}.  Try Manipulate[
 Graphics[Point[{pt[[2]], -pt[[1]]}], PlotRange -> 2, 
  Axes -> True], {pt, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}]

Comment: @Dominic Thanks! I think this should be accepted as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I post it as an answer.  I probable should have done that rather than just a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to specify {xmin,ymin},{xmax,ymax}. Try:

```
 Manipulate[ Graphics[Point[{pt[[2]], -pt[[1]]}], PlotRange -> 2, Axes -> True], {pt, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}]
```